# How to elaborate regex that accept any sequence of character except whitespace and a specific word

Tags: regex

I need to define a regex that accepts any sequence of character except whitespace and a specific word "abc".

I tryed:

```
^(?!\\s*).+(?:(?!abc).)+$
```

and similar ones but it isn't working... :(

Comment: Can you give samples and expected matches / failures? Your wording is unclear

Comment: Use `^(?:(?!abc)\S)+$` or `^(?!\S*abc)\S+$`.

Comment: I was thinking `^(?!\s+abc$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uHxX9/1)

Comment: Accept sequences like: "test", "123xyz1234", "/123y" and deny "" or " abc" or "abc"

Comment: I got it working using ^(?!\\s*$)(?!abc*$).+ :) but it seems badly done

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: What should be the result for `123abcdef` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be an answer:

```
^(?!\\s*$)(?!abc*$).+
```